# Estimating parameters in a model with a periodic design parameter

Tags: bayesian, estimation, experiment-design

We recently studied a model with a likelihood function of the form

$$\Pr(d_i|\omega,t_i)=(1-d_i)+(2d_i-1)\cos^2(\omega t_i),$$

where $d_i\in\{0,1\}$, $\omega$ is an estimation parameter, and $t_i$ are determined by the experimenter.  This is a set of independent but non-identically distributed Bernoulli trials (think: trying to estimate the time-varying bias of a coin).

Since this was a simple one estimation parameter, one design parameter model, we could essentially employ a first principles approach to the theory and computations (the paper is here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.3067).

Now that we plan to generalize this to multiple estimation and design parameters, I really want to make sure we are doing the most efficient thing possible.  I did a bit of searching but couldn't find anything in the literature on statistical models that depend on a periodically varying design parameter $t$.  Has anyone seen a model like this studied before?

Comment: A probability distribution cannot possibly be periodic.  If it were, its integral would either be zero or it would have to diverge.  Moreover, the formula you give here is *not* periodic in the *value* $d$; the periodicity lies in the two parameters $\omega$ and $t$.  That is handled by restricting them to a fundamental domain (a single period), at which point abstractly the problem actually gets nicer than many, because the parameters are points on a manifold *without* boundary, which eliminates the possibility of problems at a boundary.

Comment: @whuber I see your point.  Would "periodic parametric model" be a better term?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be what's going on.  But you don't really have a periodic parameter either!  As it stands, you can reparameterize $\cos(\omega t)$ by a *single* parameter $\mu \in [-1,1]$ without changing the statistical problem.  (I also assume, because it is not otherwise stated, that the expression for $\Pr(d|\omega,t)$ is given only up to a normalization constant that depends on $\mu$ and that $d$ is *a priori* constrained to lie in a bounded region independent of $\omega$ and $t$.)

Comment: @whuber I'm interested in estimating $\omega$.  I fixed a typo in the equation which may have made it confusing - sorry about that.  I also added a sentence which should clarify the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the fixes.  The typo changes nothing material, however: now the parameter $\mu=\cos^2(\omega t)$ is located in the interval $[0,1]$ instead of $[-1,1]$.  There is still only one parameter.  $\omega$ is not identifiable: from observing $(d_i)$ you can estimate $\mu$ but obviously from that estimate you cannot recover a unique value of $\omega$; it could be any real number.  *If we take $t$ to be fixed at some (known) nonzero constant,* we can estimate $\omega$ modulo $2\pi/t$, but that's all.  Perhaps $t$ varies in a given way from one trial to the next?

Comment: Right, the values of $\omega$ I can distinguish depend on the times $t$ I sample at (sort of a probabilistic generalization of the usual setting of the sampling theorem).  The point is to choose the best times to sample.  To do this, in analogy with usual signal analysis, I assume the frequencies are in some finite interval, say $[0,1]$.  Then I ask, what times should I sample at to minimize the variance in some estimator of $\omega$.

Comment: I made some edits in an effort to reflect this conversation and the information in your paper, Chris.  If I have erred, please forgive me and make any necessary corrections.  (One thing to be careful of is to distinguish this setting from a time-series problem, which it is not, despite your analogy with a time-varying coin.)

Comment: Am I mistaken in reading this question and seeing in it an implicit assumption of some form of *coherence*, i.e., the phase is somehow known at the start of the experiment. Also, I see no constraints, e.g., some cost associated with each sample. But, presumably that's in the paper, which I haven't looked at.

Comment: Just jumping in as a co-author on the original paper. In our model, the measurement times $t$ are something that we want to choose in order to learn as much about $\omega$ as possible. Another point to our model is that $\omega$ is the right parameter to consider, as the value of $\omega$ is independent of $t$, while $\mu$ is a periodic function of $t$.

Comment: @cardinal: We could add an initial phase uncertianty, but that would complicate the model. Given that there is a reasonable physical argument for knowing the initial phase, we decided to stick to the case of one unknown parameter for our first paper on the topic.